# Copy From beginning to End of String in C++ , Concatenate and Show in Messagebox

Tags: c++

Good evening all,

I have a problem, and its about strings. 
Now for instance i have this function `int NameInfo(*NAME nameinfo, void buf, int len)` and the buffer `buf` contains things like Firstname, LastName, Address, Telnum etc and I want to fetch and copy information from beginning to end of string there like so

```
int newNameInfo(DWORD nameinfo,void buf, int len )
{
    if(strcmp(buf,"SENTDATA",6)==0)
    {
        //find position of name
        char* name = strstr(buf, "Firstname:");
        //find position of telnum
        char* name = strstr(buf, "Telnum:");
        //copy from beginning of string to end of string - problem
    }
}
```

Now here is my problem, i want it to copy the beginning of the string to end of string , suppose my name is `FirstName: Bayern` for first name, it copies it and if my Number is `TelNum: 097852356` and it copies all from begging to end as well , then uses concatenation and put the string together in a messagebox.

This is what  i have been trying to achieve , not getting good results, need help here pls

Comment: If I were you I would use a [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) and all of its convenient member functions

Comment: The length of the string can be given by end - start, your problem is that you also have the preceeding string length to account for as well as larger issues with the types you pass to strcmp. You should be using the safe functionality  (_s) if available and finally you don't indicate what window system you intend to display the message on which would determine the call for the MessageBox.

Comment: So, how did you try to try to do it? If you show us, we can tell you, where you went wrong. Also your code couldn't even begin to compile (parameter type `void`, redefinition of `name`). Please provide an [mcve](/help/mcve), that shows an example input and an example output (at least the console version of it)

Comment: @jay, I'm running a windows OS. that's what., um ok could you show me an example of how to copy from beginning to end of a string, maybe do I have to make a function or something

Comment: See strcopy(_s) for the copy. See the library your already working in to obtain the input for how it needs to show the MessageBox, you could also just write it out to stdout.

Comment: void buf? please post real code.